# Getting desktop device id using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

I am working on a `jump to page short cut` option in the login page of one of my projects. This will basically lists a few pages in a dropdown of the login page. User can choose one among them to navigate to that page directly post login. I have a `personalise jump to page short cut` page and user can add his favourite pages to this dropdown. Now the question is about the storage. I was initially planning to store these favourite pages in the local storage. Since it is browser specific, if the user opens the app in another browser, the data won't be available. My second thought was to get a unique id for the desktop and store the data in the server using this unique desktop / machine id. Is there any way to get this id using JS / Angular JS.

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Even if you store such id at the server side, how would it help you when the user uses a different PC?

Comment: The usual UX design is to attach such personalization to the user account, hence stored server side. Once user logs in, you know the account preferences and can act accordingly.

Comment: @GuyYogev - I don't have that requirement. My requirement is just for the same PC.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-browser sessions can never be supported because of security reasons (A web application is inherently not allowed to directly write to a file system and is allowed to only access local storage, that too the area allotted to the particular application).

Thus, one browser application will never be able to know what the application wrote for the second browser as they can't use the same local storage which means, they can never really share the states.

You can read more about Local Storages [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

on the other hand, If you actually create a web_app for the browser, then you should be able to get permissions to write to file-system and thus, the same application can work across browsers.